# Understanding Python function arg notation like this: str.find(sub[, start[, end]])

Tags: python

Can someone describe what's happening syntactically in functions like functions like `str.find(sub[, start[, end]])`? I don't understand what the function arguments are doing or supposed to be.

For one thing, what is the `[, x]` construct?

Comment: Maybe you will find [this][1] answer useful.


  [1]: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/39535/argument-notation-in-python-documentation/39538#39538

Comment: @Robert- that link does explain it, thanks- If you want to refactor it into an answer here I'll give you cred.

Comment: Alright. I will try to find a more complete answer, though. A lot of broken links out there :-)

Comment: Think we got around to it w David's answer- thanks for the link though

Comment: No problem. I added an answer in case anyone else wants a thorough description of the notation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This square bracket notation is used to denote optional arguments. You can omit them if you wish and thus invoke default behaviour. The optional arguments will always be described in the documentation.

Note that the square brackets used in the documentation are not part of Python itself. You can never write that in a Python program. It is purely a notational convention used in documentation.

Comment: It means you can call it 3 different ways: `find(sub)`, `find(sub, start)` or `find(sub, start, end)`. In the first way, start is assumed to be 0 and end is assumed to be -1. In the second, you provide start and end is assumed to be -1. In the last, nothing is assumed. Is the issue that you don't understand slice notation?

Comment: There are two different notations involving square brackets going on here. One is in the documentation for how to call a function, where square brackets are used to denote optional arguments as this answer states. The other is within code itself, where square brackets denote a list (and colons within [] indicate a slice of a list).

Comment: David- "You can never write that in a Python program. It is purely a notational convention used in documentation" - this is what I was looking for

Comment: Good. It just took a little back and forth with you to work out exactly where the blockage in understanding lay. Glad we've cleared it up.

Comment: And Vicky- good point- that indeed what was initially confusing me.

Answer (score 2):

I leave this for future reference:

[A similar question in programmer.se](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39535/argument-notation-in-python-documentation/39538#39538)

A [link](http://docs.python.org/reference/introduction.html#notation) to Python documentation. Basically:

> Each rule begins with a name (which is the name defined by the rule)
>   and ::=. A vertical bar (|) is used to separate alternatives; it is
>   the least binding operator in this notation. A star (*) means zero or
>   more repetitions of the preceding item; likewise, a plus (+) means one
>   or more repetitions, and a phrase enclosed in square brackets ([ ])
>   means zero or one occurrences (in other words, the enclosed phrase is
>   optional). The * and + operators bind as tightly as possible;
>   parentheses are used for grouping. Literal strings are enclosed in
>   quotes. White space is only meaningful to separate tokens. Rules are
>   normally contained on a single line; rules with many alternatives may
>   be formatted alternatively with each line after the first beginning
>   with a vertical bar.